# would exceptions be a reasonable way to return different types?

Tags: c++, exception, return-type

I've been wondering: since exceptions can be of any type, would they be viable for returning a different type depending on the conditions?

I know it's not very clear so I'll make an example: for a messaging app, we want the users to be able to send their position, but for privacy reasons, we want it to only be shown if the user is online:

```cpp
void get_user_position(User& u) {
    if(!u.is_online()) throw false;
    else throw u.get_position();
}

void send_user_position(User& u) {
    try {
        get_user_position(u);
    } catch(bool e) {
        //send a message like "user isn't online"
    } catch(user_position e) {
        //send the position
    }
}
```

This would avoid the need for `-1`s as failed operation flags and stuff like that. Thoughts? Opinions? Am I completely missing something?

Comment: I would prefer using a `std::optional`, this just seems like the wrong tool for the job. Returning different types is not where the branching should happen in a statically typed language.

Comment: @super this was just the first example I could think of, not the actual use case. anyway, the answer turn out to be `std::variant`

Comment: `std::variant<std::monostate,user_position>` might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceptions should be used for exceptions and not for normal conditional code parts. If "not online" is now an exception is matter of taste.

But if your question is more general and asks about giving back different return types from a single function you should think of using [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant). With [std::holds_alternative](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/holds_alternative) you can *ask* which type was stored in the variant. There are several methods to deal with the content of variants e.g. [std::visit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit)

```
struct A{};
struct B{};


std::variant < A,B > Func( int x)
{
    if ( x == 0 ) return A{};
    return B{};
}

int main()
{
    auto v = Func( 0 );
    if ( std::holds_alternative<A>(v) )
    {
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    }
    else if ( std::holds_alternative<B>(v) )
    {
        std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
    }

    // or even use std::visit or whatever is helpful...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely not. You don't bring a sword to the table to cut vegetables. In this case, its not even a sword. Its a brush.

Jokes apart, looking at what you want to do, this means you already know what possible types of the return value are. Since that's the case, use [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Answer (score 1):

So long as all the exceptions you use in this way are derived from a common base class, e.g.

```
struct payload_base_class : public std::exception
{
};
```

then I can see that this pattern of yours could be useful. I've mandated this commonality so you can distinguish between your `return`-flavour exceptions over ones that you should treat in a more standard fashion.

(It's possible that you might not want `std::exception` as the base class, else your exceptions might be caught unintentionally. That's for you to study.)

This technique has an advantage over a `std::variant` approach in that you can add new `return` types without having to change the `std::variant` template; doing that latter can introduce breaking changes.

C++ is designed to allow such exploits. Just because folk didn't have this use-case in mind when exceptions were developed doesn't make this approach illegitimate. Template metaprogamming grew up unintentionaly too.

Comment: couldn't i just use `auto` in the return type to avoid rewriting the return type every time?